# Add class using jquery based on scroll postion and page id

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following jQuery code that adds a class to the menu based on the scroll position of the page and it works fine.

```
myshop_sticky_header: function () {
        if ( myshop_global_frontend.myshop_enable_sticky_menu == 1 ) {
            var _head   = document.getElementById('header'),
                _cat    = document.getElementsByClassName('block-nav-category')[ 0 ],
                _sticky = document.getElementById('header-sticky-menu'),
                _height = _head.getBoundingClientRect().height;

            if ( $(window).scrollTop() > _height + 100 ) {
                _sticky.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                _sticky.classList.remove('active');
                if ( _cat != null ) {
                    _cat.classList.remove('has-open');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get that to work such if the page id is 2, then the scroll position should be +500 else, the code above. I am trying to implement this on a wordpress site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to add JS based on page id then you can use the WordPress function

// When Page 2 (ID) is being displayed.
if(is_page( 2 ))
{
   // Your JS for page ID 2 scroll position should be +500
}
else
{
  ?>
  <script>
myshop_sticky_header: function () {
        if ( myshop_global_frontend.myshop_enable_sticky_menu == 1 ) {
            var _head   = document.getElementById('header'),
                _cat    = document.getElementsByClassName('block-nav-category')[ 0 ],
                _sticky = document.getElementById('header-sticky-menu'),
                _height = _head.getBoundingClientRect().height;

            if ( $(window).scrollTop() > _height + 100 ) {
                _sticky.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                _sticky.classList.remove('active');
                if ( _cat != null ) {
                    _cat.classList.remove('has-open');
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JS, you can check if body has class `page-id-2`. In jQuery for example, that could be done with this:

```
if($('body').hasClass('page-id-2'))
{
    //do your +500 stuff
}
else
{
    //do your regular stuff
}
```